# Drawing Text On Applications

Tags: python

I really want to draw onto an application window.
For example, I want it to display 'Hello World' on the discord window at the top left. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do that, you will need to download themes from internet for discord, maybe with BetterDiscord or something, then in the css file you will need some simple css knowledge about the coordinates/placement, and the text you want to display.

Comment: I understand this, however I'm trying to write something on Arma 3's interface like at the top left. I just want the text to be visible on the screen, not directly on the interface if necessary however I don't want it to be a separate window (like a 3rd party crosshair)

Comment: i am really sorry to hear that you are looking for a gaming section on SO. This is not a place for gaming, or gaming related. Please keep in my mind this in your next thread. However, coming to the thing that you want, with simple search, you can achieve what you have wanted, here are some examples:
https://hudsight.com/